# getting the following error message from the code "Unexpected end of JSON input"

Tags: jquery, html, json

trying to save some of the content into JSON objects however it seems to break at some instances where there's an apostrophe on any word for example :
my function looks like this:

```
function escapeHtml(text) {
        var map = {
          '&': '',
          '<': '',
          '>': '',
          '"': '',
          "'": '',
          '[': '',
          ']': ''
        };
        return text.replace(/[&<>"']/g, function(m) { return map[m]; });
      }
```

Another function with the code:

```
  function updateVariable() {
    $('input.selected_programs').val('-77');
    if ($('#selected_programs li').length) {
      $('#selected_programs').show();
        $('#selected_programs li').each(function(){
          var program = JSON.parse($(this).attr('program-data')).split(',');
          var program_details;
          programId = escapeHtml(program[0]);
          for (var h = 1; h < program.length; h++) {
              program[h] = escapeHtml(program[h]);
              program[h] = program[h].replace(/\\'/g,"&#039;");
              program[h] = program[h].replace(/\\&#039;/g,"&#039;");
              program[h] = program[h].replace(/&amp;/g,"&");
              program[h] = program[h].replace(/\]/g,"");
            if (trim(program[h]) != "" && program[h] != 0 && program[h] != "-") {
              if (h == 1) {
                program_details = "<strong>"+program[h] + "</strong><br />";
              } else if (h == 2) {
                program_details = program_details + " Series: " + program[h] +";";
              } else if (h == 3) {
                program_details = program_details + " Episode: " + program[h] +";";
              } else if (h == 4) {
                program_details = program_details + " " + program[h] +";";
              } else if (h == 5) {
                program_details = program_details + " " + program[h];
              }

            }
          }
          $('input.selected_programs').each(function(){
            if($(this).val() == -77){
              $(this).val(program_details);
              return false;
            }
          });
        });
    } else {
      $('#selected_programs').hide();
    }
```

This seems to work most of the time with the format returned from the file. however, I noticed at some points when there's a " ' " in a word for example "Nicklaus's" then my code doesn't ignore the apostrophe and break the JSON format. I'm not sure where I'm failing above

here's below an example of where the code break and another example of where it works fine:

this one works right:

```
<li class="ui-li-static ui-body-inherit" program-id="1670271" program-data="&quot;[\&quot;1670271\&quot;,\&quot;2000: Official Top 10 (MTV Music (IRE))\&quot;,\&quot;0\&quot;,\&quot;0\&quot;,\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;Tune in to enjoy the biggest hits of 2000 (Music)\&quot;,\&quot;40037\&quot;,\&quot;2\&quot;]&quot;"><img src="../../../uc/custom/tpl_layout_responsive3/questiontypes/special/cQ2v2/resources/read.png" class="remove_program">2000: Official Top 10 (MTV Music (IRE)), Tune in to enjoy the biggest hits of 2000 (Music)</li>
```

The following code seems to break where the apostrophe is pointed:

```
<li class="ui-li-static ui-body-inherit" program-id="1643452" program-data="&quot;[\&quot;1643452\&quot;,\&quot;1975: The Magnificent Masters (Sky Sports Golf)\&quot;,\&quot;0\&quot;,\&quot;0\&quot;,\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;A look back at Jack Nicklaus\\\\" s="" triumph="" in="" the="" 1975="" masters="" tournament="" at="" augusta="" national="" golf="" club.="" golden="" bear="" held="" his="" nerve="" to="" win="" fifth="" green="" jacket="" (sports)\",\"51609\",\"2\"]"'=""><img src="../../../uc/custom/tpl_layout_responsive3/questiontypes/special/cQ2v2/resources/read.png" class="remove_program">1975: The Magnificent Masters (Sky Sports Golf), A look back at Jack Nicklaus's triumph in the 1975 Masters tournament at Augusta National Golf Club. The Golden Bear held his nerve to win his fifth green jacket (Sports)</li>
```

Any help with this will be much appreciated.

If it helps here's where I use programData

```
if (programData.displayCount > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < programData.data.length; i++) {
                  var program = JSON.parse(programData.data[i]);
                  var program_details;
                  var program_description;
                  for (var h = 1; h < program.length; h++) {
                    if (program[h] != "" && program[h] != 0 && program[h] != "-") {
                      program[h] = program[h].replace(/\\'/g,"&#039;");
                      program[h] = program[h].replace(/\\&#039;/g,"&#039;");
                      program[h] = program[h].replace(/&amp;/g,"&");
                      if (program_details && h < 6) {
                        program_details = program_details + ", ";
                        program_description = program_description + ", ";
                      }
                      if (h == 2) {
                        program_details = program_details + "Series: ";
                        program_description = program_description + "Series: ";
                      } else if (h == 3) {
                        program_details = program_details + "Episode: ";
                        program_description = program_description + "Episode: ";
                      } else if (h == 4) {
                        program_details = program_details;
                        program_description = program_description;
                      } else if (h == 5) {
                        program_details = program_details;
                        program_description = program_description;
                      }
                      if (h < 6) {
                        if (h != 1) {
                          program_details = program_details + program[h];
                          program_description = program_description + program[h];
                        } else {
                          program_details = program[h];
                          program_description = program[h];
                        }
                      }
                      if (h==4 || h==5) {
                        program_description = program_description;
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  $("#program_select").append("<option class='select-option' value='"+program[0]+"' program-details ='"+program_details+"' program-data='"+JSON.stringify(programData.data[i])+"' title='"+program[5]+"'>"+program_description+"</option>");
                }
```

To add extra HTML as most requested :

here's the HTML of the part that is broken before it has been added to the list:

```
<option class="select-option" value="1413499" program-details="13 Minutes: The Plot to Assassinate Adolf Hitler (BBC Two Northern Ireland), World War II drama. In November 1939, Georg Elser's attempt to assassinate Hitler fails, and he is arrested. During his confinement, he recalls the events leading up to his plot. (Movie )" program-data="&quot;[\&quot;1413499\&quot;,\&quot;13 Minutes: The Plot to Assassinate Adolf Hitler (BBC Two Northern Ireland)\&quot;,\&quot;0\&quot;,\&quot;0\&quot;,\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;World War II drama. In November 1939, Georg Elser\\\\'s attempt to assassinate Hitler fails, and he is arrested. During his confinement, he recalls the events leading up to his plot. (Movie )\&quot;,\&quot;519\&quot;,\&quot;2\&quot;]&quot;" title="World War II drama. In November 1939, Georg Elser's attempt to assassinate Hitler fails, and he is arrested. During his confinement, he recalls the events leading up to his plot. (Movie )">13 Minutes: The Plot to Assassinate Adolf Hitler (BBC Two Northern Ireland), World War II drama. In November 1939, Georg Elser's attempt to assassinate Hitler fails, and he is arrested. During his confinement, he recalls the events leading up to his plot. (Movie )</option>
```

Comment: Could you provide us with samples of before and after that show the unexpected behaviour?

Comment: so the error is in `JSON.parse($(this).attr('program-data'))` ? could you show how you set `program-data`?

Comment: Yes the error on JSON.parse()

Comment: $('button#add_program').on('click', function(e,){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('<li class="ui-li-static ui-body-inherit" program-id="'+$('#program_select option:selected').val()+'" program-data=\''+$('#program_select option:selected').attr("program-data")+'\'><img src="'+removeImg+'" class="remove_program" />'+$('#program_select option:selected').attr("program-details")+'</li>').appendTo('div#selected_programs ul');

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you looking for.!

Comment: Can you put whole html in your question so we can more idea at what time updateVariable() function call

Comment: `$('<li program-data="' + value + '"></li>')` will only work if value is html escaped, i would recommend using `$('<li></li>').attr('program-data', value).appendTo('div#selected_programs ul');` instead.

Answer (score 0):

try not using single quotes with json instead use double quotes like this ("")